# Align text and bottom of forest tree

Tags: forest, trees

How can I align text around forest tree's bottom node?

```
Fox
\begin{forest}
[PAST [jumped]]
\end{forest}
over fence
```

[image]

Or are there more cleaner ways to insert text above words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You *can* definitely use forest here and set the `baseline` wherever you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
Fox
\begin{forest}
[PAST [jumped,baseline]]
\end{forest}
over fence

Fox \tikz[baseline=(j.base),outer xsep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt]{\draw (0,0) node[below] (j){jumped} -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above]{PAST};}
over fence
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on what you really want to achieve there are of course other options. But I do not know enough about your goals to make a choice. So I only add a `tikz` alternative (`forest` loads `tikz` as it is based on it).

If you want to just set a word on top of another word there are zillions of options like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Fox $\stackrel{\textstyle\text{PAST}}{\text{jumped}}$ 
over fence
\end{document}
```